# text1/text2 to array['text1']['text2']?

Tags: php

I'm trying to make something like

```
function config( $string ){
    require 'configuration.php';
    return $config[$string];
}
```

but i have a problem when my config has a 2D array. like:

```
$config['features'] = array(
        'memcached' => TRUE,
        'compress'  => TRUE,
        'gzip'      => TRUE
);
```

how can i get `config('features/memcached')` or if can we have three or more threaded array like `config('features/memcached/version14/etc')` ( example ) to return `true` but still works when we do something like `config('features')` returns the array just like the function above. any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just split the string into keys:

```
function config( $string ){
    require 'configuration.php';
    $keys = explode('/',$string);
    $return = $config;
    foreach($keys as $key){
        $return = $return[$key];
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Here you can do this too:

```
config('features/others/foo/bar');
```

if this exists:

```
$config['features'] = array(
    'memcached' => TRUE,
    'others'  => array( 'foo' => array( 'bar' => 42 ) )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try this (written from head, not tested):

```
function config( $key, $subkey = null ){

    require 'configuration.php';

    return ($subkey)? $config[$key][$subkey] : $config[$key];

}
```

use it as `config('features','memcached')` and note that this will only work with one level of sub-arrays. if there could be more or if you want to stick to the `config('features/memcached')`-syntax, you could try something like this (same as the function above - this isn't tested, maybe you'll have to fix a bug on your own ;) ):

```
function config( $string ){

    require 'configuration.php';

    $keys = explode('/',$string);

    foreach($keys as $key){
        $config = $config[$key];
    }

    return $config;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use that aproach:

```
public function config($path = null, $separator = '.')
{
    if (!$path) {
        return self::$_constants;
    }

    $keys = explode($separator, $path);
    require 'configuration.php';
    $value = $config;
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        if (!isset($value[$key])) {
            throw new Exception("Value for path $path doesn't exists or it's null");
        }
        $value = $value[$key];
    }
    return $value;
}
```

In your example calling `config('features')` will return array, and `config('features.compres')` will return `true` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

```
function config( $string ){
    require 'configuration.php';
    $p = explode("/",$string);
    $r =  $config;
    foreach($p as $param)
        $r = $r[$param];
    return $r;
}
```